# php algorithm for picking next person up in round Robin fashion

Tags: php

Okay, I have a list of people in a database, can you point me to some sample coding that will show me a good algorithm to determine who the next person in line is?
 Because people can be added to the list in mid stream, so not sure how to always pick who is next.

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and I'm frustrated.

If I have 10 people and I'm on number 3 and 11 comes in, they'd have to go to the back, right?  So next up is 4, but they'd go behind 3, because after 10 it starts over at 1, then 2 and 3, so after that 11 can come in...

Wow, this is complex.

I cannot wrap my brain around it.
Do you know of some algorithm I can go look at to wrap my head around it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you have a fixed size [Circular Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

You need two indexes into the buffer:

- one indicating where the end of the queue is, and,
- one indicating where the beginning of the queue is.

You also need the concepts that the buffer can have the condition:

- Empty: so there is no one to wait on or serve, and,
- Full: as the buffer is fixed in size, and potentially full,
     a full buffer cannot accept new entries.

Both conditions (full/empty) are detected by comparing the index associated with the beginning of the queue with the index associated with the end of the queue.  The test for empty and full are each just slightly different test, and, all depends on how you define the meaning of those two indexes.  See the Wikipedia article for more info.